# Search for sites returns 403 Access Denied

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api

We've seen a change in functionality with the Microsoft Graph `/sites?search` endpoint.

Within the past couple of days, when making this call:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites?search=
```

for certain tenants, we now receive:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "accessDenied",
        "message": "The caller does not have permission to perform the action.",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "a37ae18e-dcd2-481d-bb06-0a0f5cade4f4",
            "date": "2018-09-28T13:54:56"
        }
    }
}
```

We are using app only authentication with the following roles:

```
"roles": [
    "Directory.Read.All",
    "User.Read.All"
  ],
```

Has there been a change in permissions required for this call?

Answer (score 4):

[According to the documentation](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/site_search), you need either `Sites.Read.All` or `Sites.ReadWrite.All` in order to use `/sites?search={query}`.